# PHP7.4 Session storage on Redis issue

Tags: php, session, nginx, phpredis, php-7.4

I upgraded PHP version from 7.1 to 7.2, 7.3, 7.4.

And after updgrading I am facing issue with Session storage on Redis.

I am trying to configure my application with

> Php 7.4
>
> Php-redis 5.2.1
>
> Yii 2.0.15
>
> Nginx 1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
>
> Ubuntu 18.04

In my application configuration,
i have set

```
session_save_path("tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?auth=admin123&prefix=AT_R_");
```

when i try to run the application, i am getting the following error:

> [error] 21728#21728: *1081 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message:
> yii\base\InvalidArgumentException: Session save path is not a valid
> directory: tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?auth=admin123&prefix=AT_R_ in
> /var/www/php-aertrip/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Session.php:352

The strange thing is,
the same code settings with **Php 7.1 runs perfectly**, but **does not work with 7.2, 7.3 and now at 7.4.**

I am not able to find any reason for this to not work. Kindly suggest what might be the cause of this issue.

Any Help is appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems odd to be saving sessions remotely and/or via a TCP channel..... ?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:6379 is redis installed on localhost

Answer (score 2):

LE:
So actually using `ini_set()` also works in the scope of an app.

```
ini_set('session.save_handler','redis');
ini_set('session.save_path','tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?auth=admin123&prefix=AT_R_');
```

--

Ubuntu 18.04 / PHP 7.4.9 here.
I've just setup PHP to run with Redis as a session handler.
In my case I've just went for the simple approach to change the PHP settings in php.ini

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://10.0.0.1:6379?auth=secretpass123"
```

A few mentions here:

- the password (if any) has to be URL encoded
- restart Apache / FPM service after every edit in the php.ini file

BUT in your case, you've mentioned that you need the PHP session handled by Redis only for a specific app. So I was curious if that can be achieved.
For that I've used the default php.ini settings with `session.save_handler = files` and the `session.save_path` commented out.
So to achieve this the `session_set_save_handler` function should be used https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

> session_set_save_handler() sets the user-level session storage functions which are used for storing and retrieving data associated with a session. This is most useful when a storage method other than those supplied by PHP sessions is preferred, e.g. storing the session data in a local database.

I've also used this guide to come to a full working example (obviously this shouldn't be used in production) https://developpaper.com/how-to-use-redis-to-save-user-session-details/

```
<?php
class SessionManager
{

private $redis;
private $sessionSavePath;
private $sessionName;
private $session_expiretime = 60;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->redis = new Redis();// Create phpredis instance
    $this->redis->connect('10.0.0.1', 6379); // connect redis
    $this->redis->auth("secretpass123"); // authorization
    session_set_save_handler(
        array($this, "open"),
        array($this, "close"),
        array($this, "read"),
        array($this, "write"),
        array($this, "destroy"),
        array($this, "gc")
    );
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
}

public function open($path, $name)
{
    return true;
}

public function close()
{
    return true;
}

public function read($id)
{
    $value = $this->redis->get($id); // Get the specified record in redis
    if ($value) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

public function write($id, $data)
{

    if ($this->redis->set($id, $data)) {
        // stored with session ID as the key
        $this->redis->expire($id, $this->session_expiretime); // Set the expiration time of data in redis, that is, session expiration time
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    if ($this->redis->delete($id)) {// delete the specified record in redis
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function gc($maxlifetime)
{
    return true;
}

public function __destruct()
{
    session_write_close();
}
}


$handler = new SessionManager();

if (isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    echo ++$_SESSION['test'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['test'] = 0;
    echo 'not set - 0';
}
```

Instantiating the SessionManager class will set the session handler to Redis. This comes with a small test that upon successive page reloads will create and increment a counter.
You can connect to the redis server and run a flushall command and observe how the counter gets reset.

One mention is to have the php-redis extension enabled.

```
$ php -m | grep redis
```

Should display 'redis'.
If not, that can be installed (in Ubuntu) like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-redis
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't target the issue. i've tried this. 
the issue is when we set session (to the frontend app from within the backend app) before we redirect to frontend app. In doing so, the session is getting reset when the app is initialised after redirect. 
strangely this was working till 7.1.* but started failing from 7.2.* onwards

work around applied -- don't set session from backend, first redirect and then set session

Comment: @Gunnrryy OK, but then your issue may lie elsewhere. Would recommend updating your question and providing an overview of the architecture of your apps, or how your apps interact, as the issue may have something to do with something particular in the architecture. Also would recommend updating to the latest version of PHP. It seems there was an issue related to session that was fixed in 7.4.* https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php